# Is it possible to submit a new version of an app to the ITunes app store while keeping the current version's status "Ready For Sale"?

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I am afraid that if I upload the new version, the current version may become inactive while I will have to wait for the new version to be reviewed for another week. Would this really happen or not? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens to the current version when you submit an update. The update is handled separately while the current version sits there just fine for users to download.